# Checking if two jar classes are the same

Tags: unix

So Im trying to figure out if two .jars have the same .class file name.

I've done this -

```
cat jarFilePaths | xargs -n 1 jar tf | grep 'joda'
```

What do I do to see if two of these have the same .class file name. jarFilePaths is a list of file paths of jars.

Answer (score 0):

Using uniq, you can filter out the duplicates. I'd imagine you'd want the inverse of that, or the [-d option](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?uniq) to print out only duplicate lines:

```
cat jarFilePaths | xargs -n 1 jar tf | grep 'joda' | grep '\.class' | sort | uniq -d
```

Should solve your issue. If not, do leave a comment, indicating where you are still having problems.